# ImageButton in ViewBinder doesn't work

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-viewbinder

I created a `ViewBinder`, to hold my items in a `ListView`, which get its contents from a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and in this there's a `ImageButton`. I successfully get the list but the `ImageButton` just won't respond to my `onclick` event to bring a string from the data base to another `Activity`. That is the problem I have.

```
public class ChannelViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    private ChannelDB mDB;
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, final Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            final Context mContext = null;
                if(view instanceof ImageView) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                        byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length));
                        return true;
                }

              if(view instanceof ImageButton) {
                           ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view;
                        ib.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {     
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                String dblink = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDB.KEY_DBLINK));
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setClass(mContext, Doubanframe.class);
                                Bundle bunde = new Bundle();
                                bunde.putString("dblink",dblink);
                                intent.putExtras(bunde);
                                }
                            });

                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

and below is my  `MainActivity` class:

```
private Button likebutton;
    private ImageButton about;
    private ChannelDB mDB;
    private ListView channellist;
    private Cursor c;


    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        likebutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        about =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.about);
        channellist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Channel);

        mDB = new ChannelDB(this);

        String[] columns = {mDB.KEY_ID, mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_PATH, mDB.KEY_DBLINK};
        String   table   = mDB.channelS_TABLE;

        c = mDB.getHandle().query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.channelview,
                c,
                new String[] {mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_DBLINK},
                new int[] {R.id.poster, R.id.channel, R.id.douban});

        adapter.setViewBinder(new ChannelViewBinder());

        channellist.setAdapter(adapter);

        channellist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                c.moveToPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(HDtvs.this,Showlist.class);
                intent .putExtra("path",mDB.KEY_PATH);
                intent .putExtra("cname",mDB.KEY_CHANNEL);
                intent .putExtra("dblink",mDB.KEY_DBLINK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the onClickListener on your `ImageButton` you are creating a new `Intent`, but you don't seem to call **`startActivity`**? You will need to have a reference to some sort of context in order to be able to do so. Your `mContext` variable appears to be a good candidate for that, although I don't see it being set to anything but `null` in the code snippet.

You can easily add a reference to a valid Context by creating a constructor for your `ChannelViewBinder` class.

```
public class ChannelViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    private Context mContext = null;

    public ChannelViewBinder(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
...
}
```

You can then later on use it to call `mContext.startActivity(intent)` in the ImageButton's onClick. Obviously you will also need to change instantiating the object: `adapter.setViewBinder(new ChannelViewBinder(this))`, where `this` will reference your `MainActivity` class.

Comment: The answer is quite inspiring, I got the idea but don't know how to do it. how should I define that mContext to another activity,and how should I write the startActivity method in this non-activity class? Can you write me some sample plz??

Comment: I added a code snippet illustrating how to get a Context reference in your custom ViewBinder. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx,but that didn't work out as expected,I tapped on the button, nothing happened,I guess it's coz the cursor in ChannelViewBinder didn't get the right string but null, can you help me with that too? thx

Comment: You should first tidy up your code a bit and then breakpoint it to see until where things work as expected. Also keep an eye out for relevant information in LogCat. For starters I would add another `return true;` in the setValueView's second `if`. You go from there. :)